# slow performance when running multiple neural networks on single GPU

Tags: tensorflow

I have 3 separate Python processes, each running a TensorFlow session with my model loaded. The system has 1 GPU.

When I make a 3 predictions at the same time (1 per process), the prediction time is much slower than if I just make 1 prediction at a time.

I've limited the memory per model via the `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` kwarg to `0.3`.

Is there a way to get better performance (less time per response) when running models in parallel on a single GPU?

Comment: What do you mean by "better performance"? One can optimize for throughput (more requests per time unit) or for latency (less time per response, probably less requests processed in total)

Comment: Good question, I'd like to optimize for latency.

Comment: I can imagine that not the actual computation time is what makes your configuration slow, but the transfer of data from multiple locations in the memory into the GPU memory. Maybe this is why parallel predictions are slower in your case.

Comment: The way to make it faster is to use a single process with single TensorFlow runtime. TensorFlow was not optimized for the case of multiple runtimes sharing a GPU