# parallelize for loop in tensorflow for training multiple models in parallel

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I have multiple models that I want to train in parallel in tensorflow. The models are currently inside a for loop. When I tried to train the model, the training happened sequentially rather than in parallel. My question is similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955791/slow-performance-when-running-multiple-neural-networks-on-single-gpu) (but nobody answered this question). However, I am training the model and not only doing inference. One of the comments on that question is "*The way to make it faster is to use a single process with single TensorFlow runtime. TensorFlow was not optimized for the case of multiple runtimes sharing a GPU*".

In line with the above comment, I noticed that if I just make a single large model (e.g., even a single model with larger total number of parameters than multiple models in the loop combined), it executes faster (e.g., 0.19 sec/step for this large model). This is in contrast with a for loop training four different models (which takes about 0.55 sec/step for the entire for loop -- almost 4 times the larger model). Can anyone advise me how to parallelize this for loop so that all iterations of the for loop execute in parallel (i.e., in almost 0.19 sec/step for the entire loop instead of 0.55 sec/step)? All of my models are able to fit in the GPU memory.

PS: Due to the nature of my work, I am unable to use tf.while_loop since it requires the loss functions to be defined within the while_loop. Is there any other way to do this kind of parallelization of for loop on the GPU (e.g., maybe using [threading](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/threading_and_queues))? I am also not using "per_process_gpu_memory_fraction" in tensorflow since the other question above indicated that it makes things slow.

Also, is it possible to do this kind of parallelization in keras or pytorch?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I think I have the same situation... do you already have a solution?

Comment: Nope. I never found a solution to this.